My project throws an AssertionError when running org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader#loadClass
I'm encountering an unexpected AssertionError in my Spring Boot application when the LaunchedURLClassLoader attempts to load a class. According to the code, this error should never happen, but I'm facing this issue in my program, and it cannot be consistently reproduced, which has been troubling me for a long time.
Here's the relevant stack trace:
java.lang.AssertionError: Package org.apache.commons.lang3.exception has already been defined but it could not be found
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.definePackageIfNecessary(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:81)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:574)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:574)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)

I have done my best to analyze the problem. However, I haven't been able to pinpoint the root cause of this issue.
I would greatly appreciate if anyone has encountered a similar problem or has any insights into what might be causing this AssertionError. Any suggestions on further troubleshooting steps or possible solutions would be immensely helpful.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
